# The same font as latex for PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

I'm using PowerPoint to make some figures for latex. The font in the figures is not compatible with the one in latex though. How can I have the same font as latex (either in texts or formula) in PowerPoint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell us more about your computing setup: Which OS (Windows, MacOS, something else?) do you employ? Is a TeX distribution installed on your system? If so, which one, and when was it last updated?

Comment: Hey @Del. Mir, one possible source is [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/), if you know the name of the font. Computer Modern (standard font) is [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern). This is for Windows...

Comment: @Mico Hi, my OS is Windows 10 and I use TeXstudio.

Comment: TeXstudio is a front end, *not* a TeX distribution. Do you use MikTeX or TeXlive? When did you last update your TeX distribution?

Comment: @Mico I use MikTex, but the problem is the fonts in equations when I use powerpoint.

Answer (score 3):

The default font of LaTeX is Computer Modern which is only available as bitmap fonts.  However, there are a few clones which resemble it very closely in OpenType format:

1. **Latin Modern**

   http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download
2. **Computer Modern Unicode**

   Despite the name this does not provide the exact same shapes as the original Computer Modern.

   https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/download.html

In both cases, go to the download page and select the OTF files.  Then follow Microsoft's instructions to add the fonts to your system: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1

To change the math font, take a look at this post over at superuser.com: https://superuser.com/questions/1114697/select-a-different-math-font-in-microsoft-word

Comment: Also, New Computer Modern.

Answer (score 1):

I found "IguanaTex" very helpful. It is a free PowerPoint add-in that allows you to insert equations with **LaTeX format** into your PowerPoint presentation.
http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/download.html

Answer (score 0):

If you load `\usepackage{fontspec}` and compile in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use any font in your LaTeX documents that you could use in Office, with `\setmainfont`, `\setmonofont`, etc.

If you load `unicode-math`, you can also use the same OpenType math fonts as in a MathML document or the Office equation editor, with `\setmathfont`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  The question was how to use LaTeX fonts in MS Office, but you are explaining how to use MS Office fonts in LaTeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke The question was how to use *the same* fonts in both. That could mean, use Computer Modern in PowerPoint. But it could also mean, set the font in LaTeX to match the one in PowerPoint.

Comment: @HenriMenke If you disagree, and believe the question unambiguously is asking for an OpenType version of Computer Modern, consider this answer to be pointing out a potential XY-problem.

Comment: On further reflection you're right.  The phrasing in the question is a bit ambiguous, but in most cases when users talk about the “LaTeX font” they want Computer Modern.

Comment: @Davislor As I said, I want to have the same math font as latex when I write equations in powerpoint.